# How do I make a cell item of a table row bold for n seconds?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a piece of code where I am calling my server to fetch some values and update the table if that value isn't present there. After the updation, I want the user to be notified of the row where the value was updated, by making it's cell value bold for n seconds.

```
var table=document.getElementById("employee_details");

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array);

$.ajax({
    url: '/server.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"input":"calculate_charges",
           data:jsonString},
    cache: false,
    success:function(response){

        const arr3=JSON.parse(response);

        for(var i=0; i<arr3.length; i++){

            if(table.rows[i+1].cells.item(10).innerHTML!=arr3[i][2]){

                 table.rows[i+1].scrollIntoView({
                     behavior: 'smooth',
                     block: 'center'
                 });

                 table.rows[i+1].cells.item(10).innerHTML=arr3[i][2];

                 setTimeout(function(){
                       table.rows[i+1].cells.item(10).style.fontWeight = "500";
                 },7000);

                 setTimeout(function(){
                       table.rows[i+1].cells.item(10).style.fontWeight = "900";
                 },4000);
            }
        }
    }
    complete:function(){}
});
```

Upon executing the code, I keep getting this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'cells')

And the cell item doesn't get bold. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Well that means it can find the row, table.rows[i+1] is undefined

Comment: But the value gets updated. Only the style doesn't work. btw `i+1` is because of the table header row

Comment: Use an arrow function () => {} i guess it cant find i, or i has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use let in for loop:

```
for(let i=0; i<arr3.length; i++){
```

About let: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Yea,  your solution is working. Can you please explain why is that? I am a novice in this language

Comment: https://medium.com/@axionoso/watch-out-when-using-settimeout-in-for-loop-js-75a047e27a5f

Comment: because if you use var it changes the value for everyone, since each loop share the same var, with let the value does not change, each loop has its own i. Usually it does not matter until you do async code like setTimeout